# Set height of empty div to remain static when adding content

Tags: javascript, html, css

Our form has a height problem with a div used for text feedback.

On a webpage I have a empty div with an id that has a style applied to it. Javascript is applied to the div when a user enters information into a form. Before the Javascript runs and put text into the div it has only a few pixels in height, when the Javascript adds text the div gains height and pushes the form elements under it down. The form should remain static without moving on user interaction.

With text the div is 29px high. Now I can apply the following style to the div.

```
height: 29px;
```

This solution does not seem to be safe as other browsers might render differently or someone might be using a different font size.

What is the best practice solution to setting the height of an empty div to stop it changing size when text is added?

Comment: can you recreate the issue in a jsfiddle or similar?

Comment: Showing the original page would be helpful too...

Comment: I tried to get this into JSFiddle but could not get the jQuery(document).ready(function ($) to work, even after setting it to use JQuery. I'll try and create this a different way, it is basically Javascript adding content into an empty div and that div gaining height and pushing other content down.

Answer (score 0):

If you set some fixed height (say... `29px`) to the div it won't change size...
To better support different `font-size`, and/or number of lines, you can calculate that special number (29px) as the product of your `font-size` * `line-height` * `numberOfLinesYouWantToAllow`, and set this number as the div's `height` accordingly.

**CSS**

```
height: 29px;
overflow: auto;
```

Comment: I was looking at this but it is not that easy. This is what I have found for the line height, this is not supposed to be that reliable. http://bit.ly/1MsmL94